# ID is not passing from one page to another page using php and jquery , ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search bar where i am displaying all records( only titles) from different tables in database,Now along with title i want to pass id also,how to pass id from one page to another page using ajax? 
please help me to solve this issue...

```
Here is my code:
ajax_search.php:


<?php 
require_once('../config.php');
if($_GET['data']=='setLanguage') 
{
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    $_SESSION['CHOOSEN_LANGUAGE'] = $lang;
}
// FUNCTION FOR INSERT CITY BASED ON LAT LONG //
if($_GET['data']=='getCityByLatLong') 
{ 
    $browser_used=$_POST['browser_used'];
    $city_id ='';
    if($browser_used!='chrome')
    {
        $deal_lat=$_POST['lat'];
        $deal_long=$_POST['lang'];
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$deal_lat.','.$deal_long.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);

        for($j=0;$j<count($output->results[0]->address_components);$j++)
        {
            $cn=array($output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]);
            if(in_array("locality", $cn))
            {
                $city_name= $output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
            }
        }
        $sql1 = "SELECT CITY_ID FROM CITY WHERE CITY_TITLE='$city_name'";
        $result1 = mysql_query($sql1); 
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result1); 
        if($num!='') 
        {
            $city_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
            $city_id = $city_row['CITY_ID'];

        }
    }
    $city_id=100;
    if($city_id !='')
    {
        $_SESSION['CHOOSEN_CITY_ID'] = $city_id;
    }
    echo $city_id;
}
if($_GET['data']=='changeCity') 
{
    $city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
    echo $_SESSION['CHOOSEN_CITY_ID'] = $city_id;
}
//set SpecialityID in session
if($_GET['data']=='setSpeciality') 
{
    unset($_SESSION['SPECIALITY']);
    $speciality_id = $_POST['speciality_id'];
    echo $_SESSION['SPECIALITY']['ID'] = $speciality_id;
}

if($_GET['data']=='getAreaByCity') 
{
    $city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
    $sql1="SELECT CITY_AREA_ID,AREA_TITLE FROM CITY_AREA WHERE CITY_ID ='".$city_id."' AND AREA_STATUS ='1'";
    $response=mysql_query($sql1);
    echo"<option value=''>Locality</option>";
    while($row  =   mysql_fetch_assoc($response))
    {
        $id = $row['CITY_AREA_ID'];
        $title = $row['AREA_TITLE'];
        echo"<option value='$id'>$title</option>";
    }       
}

//CREATE BY RAJAN *** Search Query***
//-------------------------------------
//CREATE QUERY TO DB AND PUT RECEIVED DATA INTO ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) 
{
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    /*$querystr = "SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.FIRST_NAME,e.FIRST_NAME_AR)) AS TITLE,
    TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',s.SPECIALIZATION_TITLE,s.SPECIALIZATION_AR_TITLE)) AS SPECIALIZATION_TITLE
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    LEFT JOIN EMP_SPECIALIZATION AS sp ON sp.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN SPECIALIZATION AS s ON s.SPECIALIZATION_ID=sp.SPECIALIZATION_ID
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT AS eu ON eu.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN UNIT AS u ON u.UNIT_ID=eu.UNIT_ID
    LEFT JOIN UNIT_SERVICES AS us ON us.UNIT_ID=u.UNIT_ID
    LEFT JOIN SERVICES AS sr ON sr.SERVICES_ID=us.SERVICES_ID
    WHERE e.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.FIRST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%'
    OR s.SPECIALIZATION_TITLE LIKE '%$query%' OR s.SPECIALIZATION_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'
    OR  u.UNIT_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  OR u.UNIT_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  
    OR sr.SERVICES_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  OR sr.SERVICES_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
    ORDER BY TITLE";
    $sql = mysql_query ($querystr);
    $array = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
       $array[] = array ('label' => $row['EMPLOYEE_ID'],'value' => $row['TITLE'],);
    }*/
    $array = array();
    $querystr = "SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,TRIM(CONCAT(IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.FIRST_NAME,e.FIRST_NAME_AR),IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.LAST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME_AR))) AS TITLE,
    TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',s.SPECIALIZATION_TITLE,s.SPECIALIZATION_AR_TITLE)) AS DEPARTMENT
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    LEFT JOIN EMP_SPECIALIZATION AS sp ON sp.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN SPECIALIZATION AS s ON s.SPECIALIZATION_ID=sp.SPECIALIZATION_ID
    WHERE e.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.FIRST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%'
    OR s.SPECIALIZATION_TITLE LIKE '%$query%' OR s.SPECIALIZATION_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
    ORDER BY TITLE";
    $sql = mysql_query ($querystr);

    $cnt =  mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
       $array[] = array ('value' => $row['TITLE']."  --From Specilization");
    }

    $querystr = "SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,TRIM(CONCAT(IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.FIRST_NAME,e.FIRST_NAME_AR),IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.LAST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME_AR))) AS TITLE,
    TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',u.UNIT_TITLE,u.UNIT_AR_TITLE)) AS DEPARTMENT
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT AS eu ON eu.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN UNIT AS u ON u.UNIT_ID=eu.UNIT_ID
    WHERE e.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.FIRST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%'
    OR  u.UNIT_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  OR u.UNIT_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
    ORDER BY TITLE";
    $sql = mysql_query ($querystr);

    $cnt =  mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
       $array[] = array ('value' => $row['TITLE']."  --From Unit");
    }

    $querystr = "SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,TRIM(CONCAT(IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.FIRST_NAME,e.FIRST_NAME_AR),IF('$LANG' = 'en',e.LAST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME_AR))) AS TITLE,
    TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',sr.SERVICES_TITLE,sr.SERVICES_AR_TITLE)) AS DEPARTMENT
    FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT AS eu ON eu.EMPLOYEE_ID=e.EMPLOYEE_ID
    LEFT JOIN UNIT AS u ON u.UNIT_ID=eu.UNIT_ID
    LEFT JOIN UNIT_SERVICES AS us ON us.UNIT_ID=u.UNIT_ID
    LEFT JOIN SERVICES AS sr ON sr.SERVICES_ID=us.SERVICES_ID
    WHERE e.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.FIRST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME LIKE '%$query%' OR e.LAST_NAME_AR LIKE '%$query%'
    OR sr.SERVICES_TITLE LIKE '%$query%'  OR sr.SERVICES_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%' 
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
    ORDER BY TITLE";
    $sql = mysql_query ($querystr);

    $cnt =  mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
       $array[] = array ('value' => $row['TITLE']." --From Services ".$row['EMPLOYEE_ID']);
    }

    $querystr = "SELECT u.UNIT_ID,TRIM(IF('$LANG' = 'en',u.UNIT_TITLE,u.UNIT_AR_TITLE)) AS TITLE
    FROM  UNIT AS u 
    WHERE u.UNIT_TITLE LIKE '%$query%' OR u.UNIT_AR_TITLE LIKE '%$query%' 
    GROUP BY UNIT_ID
    ORDER BY TITLE";
    $sql = mysql_query ($querystr);
    $cnt =  mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
       $array[] = array ('value' => $row['TITLE']."  --From Clinic");
    }

    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
}
?>

search_section.php:

<div class="form-group check1">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="location">Search here for Doctor's Name, Specialities or Hospitals</label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="test_id" id="test_id" value="">
                        <input type="text" name="search_specialist" size="30" onchange="return getDetails();" class="form-control newcheck" id="location" placeholder="Search here for Doctor's Name, Specialities or Hospitals">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary prim" onclick="return getDetails();"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
                    </div>

<script>
    $('input.newcheck').typeahead({
        name: 'search_specialist',
        remote:"<?php echo CUR_URL ;?>new_template/ajax_code.php?query=%QUERY",
        limit: 100
</script>
```

Comment: Please include only relevant code, not full "random" code from your page

Answer (score 0):

Okej, ill just try to answer your question how to pass values using ajax.
First you need form:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="input" value="test"> 
</form>
```

All inputs fields values in your form will be passed.

Ajax:

```
jQuery(function(){
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) { //on submit function
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', //method POST
      url: 'yoururl.php', //URL of page where to pass values
      data: $('#form').serialize(), //seriallize is passing all inputs values of form
      success: function(){ //on success function
              $("#input").attr("disabled", true); //example
              $("#input").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');//example
                  },
    });
}
});
```

Note(If u want to pass some value which u dont want users to see on page) you can still add input with display block, example:

```
<input type="text" name="akcija" value="<?php echo $row['akcija']; ?>" style="display:none;" />
```

And on the ajax page you can get values by

```
$akcija = $_POST['akcija']
```